# Alternatives to NSURLConnection + NSXMLParser to download and display XML data?

Tags: xml, ios

Until now I've been using NSURLConnection and NSXMLParser to do this, but it is really tedious.

What alternatives are available? How are you obtaining and parsing your XML data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

LibXML is nice (and included with the SDK). It can do DOM-style parsing (i.e. parse everything at once and let you crawl around the tree back and forth), and it can parse HTML, too.